# .Net Framework 4.0 on Windows XP

Tags: .net, windows-xp

I would like to confirm whether .Net Framework 4.0 (v4.0.30319) is supported on Windows XP Professional SP2? On many Microsoft download links, I found that .Net Framework 4.0 is only supported on Windows XP SP3 and above. But while I gave it a try on a fresh Windows XP SP2 VM it only asked for 2 things.

1. Windows Installer 3.1
2. Windows Imaging Components.

And the installation went smooth and completed. Now how can I be sure whether .Net Framework 4.0 is actually going to work on any Windows XP versions?

Comment: Windows XP is dead and gone. It's well beyond end-of-life, and is no longer being supported. .Net 4.0 was only *officially* supported on XP SP3 and above, as you've already read, which means using it on anything prior to that was not supported. If it happens to work, fine, but don't depend on it always doing so. XP is gone, may it rest in peace.

Comment: @KenWhite: Well things that work now will continue to work, because there will be absolutely no updates to XP.  My largest concern in this scenario is that there will be no security updates to XP, leaving the overall platform vulnerable to new threats.

Comment: @EricJ: My point was that just because it worked on XP SP2 the poster should not count on it working there. I mentioned that it was dead/beyond EOL/no longer supported as well. If the poster wants to keep using an OS that is no longer receiving updates (and that is known to be the target of malware authors)...

Comment: Just saying that if a certain .NET 4 program works right now on XP SP2, it will continue to work because absolutely nothing will change.  He can indeed count on it continuing to work because there will be zero changes to the operating system.  Any changes at all to the .NET program of course could create a case that does not run on SP2.

Comment: Any Microsoft/MSDN official links where it says .Net 4.0 is only supported on XP SP3? I couldn't found one except on download page.

Answer (score 0):

Windows XP is [no longer supported](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/WindowsForBusiness/end-of-xp-support) by Microsoft.  The current [.NET versions are also not supported on Windows XP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z6watww(v=vs.110).aspx), though as you mention .NET 4 on SP3 is.  There are reasons that Microsoft did not extend support to pre-SP3, so assume that some things just do not work.

I hate to quote marketing material, but in this case it is dead on.  From the first link:

> There will be no more security updates or technical support for the Windows XP operating system. It is very important that customers and partners migrate to a modern operating system such as Windows 8.1.

I would not expect anything more than significant security issues to be fixed in .NET 4.  Most bug fixes and of course all enhancements will happen in the latest version.

It may well work, but continuing to run XP

- You may encounter .NET framework errors that will never be addressed
- You leave yourself open to security vulnerabilities, both in .NET running on XP and in XP itself.

Comment: I understand what you said all. But shall I consider than even after a successful installation of .Net Framework 4 on Windows XP SP2 it can fail to run application or so?

Comment: Yes.  Some things from the .NET Framework 4 will almost certainly not work on SP2, which is why Microsoft required SP3 and later for support.  Some features of .NET 4 just need to rely on either features or bug fixes introduced in SP3.  Your specific application may or may not use those features, so your specific application may or may not run correctly.

Comment: Yeah. I also feel that. But actually I was looking for some microsoft official link which can confirm me the same.

Comment: Windows XP being no longer supported should be reason enough to move away from Windows XP, regardless of whether .NET 4 will run there.  Is there a compelling reason you can't at least upgrade to SP3 (which should be free), if not upgrade to a supported operating system?

Comment: The System Requirements in the download page is official.  I think you already saw that, but here it is just in case http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17113

Comment: Yes. That's the only resource I found, no other msdn/microsoft link.